# Dialogflow LinkOutSuggestion Chips are not rendering in simulator

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have an intent which doesnt need any webhhok call to respond so I added LinkoutSuggestion in intent UI response. When I am triggering this intent it is showing the chip on web console under google assisant but It is not showing it when I am testing it on simulator. Please see the attachments

WEB
[image]

But on google assistant simulator it is showing only the simple response text, not the linkoutsuggestion chips. The link in suggestionchip is successfully verified

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you simulator is set to Smart Displays as a platform. Smart Displays do not have access to a browser at the moment so any element that requires a browser isn't shown on these devices.

[image]

If you switch the platform to phone, the link out suggestion will show up. Also remember to click on the display tab in the simulator, most visual elements are only shown here.

[image]

Comment: Yes. thank you for the answer. I just figured it out when I tried it for basic card. I also want to enter the attached link text in chat window as a reply instead of opening the browser tab. Can you help how to do this.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean, you just want google assistant to say the link?

Comment: Basically I want to take action when user click on that LinkoutSuggestion Chip. So when user clicks on this link chip I want to trigger an event

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible. You cant detect when someone clicks a LinkOut suggestion. The elements that do support click events are lists and carousels https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/selection-responses#top_of_page

Comment: Ok, then how can I move to next question or intent if I can not detect user took some action? Is there any way so that webhook can automatically respond after some time?

Comment: The conversation should move forward by the user answering to your question. Google Assistant is made to respond to the user. It doesn't really support automatic replies or events after opening links.

Comment: ok, Thank you for the help Jordi. I have one last question regarding the same.- Is this achievable that after user triggers the event, webhook send back some response and then after 5 secs trigger a followup event?

Comment: If you want to trigger an event - don't use a Link Out suggestion. Just use a suggestion chip, which acts like the user said that.

Comment: If you have an additional, unrelated, question - it is best raised as a new StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

it might be late for the answer but can be helpful for others.
So I went into the same problem where I was not getting the **linkOutSuggestion** chip but the problem is sligtly different In my case it was working everywhere while development, in every device I was testing on. But the **linkoutsuggestion** chip stopped working when I released/deployed on alpha for testing with limited users.

I got to know by my findings that it is a part of **Brand Verfication**.
The Website needs to be verified than only it will allow your action to show the **linkoutSuggestion** to your users device.

[image]

You can refer this here : https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/brand-verification

Hope this is helpful
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

For Actions, don't use the Dialogflow simulator; it doesn't support all the Actions rich responses. Use the Actions simulator in the Actions Console: https://console.actions.google.com/

Comment: I tried on Actions simulator as well. It is showing only the simple response but not the LinkoutSuggestion chips.